# Skip or ignore part of string while searching string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need some help with this code:

```
let loc;
let ftd = "17";   //ftd = first two digits
let x = "number1701:oknumber1203:ok"
```

Now I want to search this string but skip the third and fourth digit (represented by XX).

```
loc = x.search(`number${ftd}XX:ok`)
```

Is this possible?

[Edit]

If i run this code the result is loc = "-1" (obviously, because the string x does not contain "number17XX:ok"
I want the program to ignore the two XX digits. The result i want is the location of the searched string in x.

Comment: please add the wanted result. and your try.

Comment: You want to search for `ftd` inside the `x` string in any occurence of `numberYYXX:ok` where YY is the `ftd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take `\d` for any digit to search. The backslash needs to be escaped as well.

```js
let ftd = "17",   //ftd = first two digits
    x = "number1701:oknumber1203:ok",
    loc = x.search(`number${ftd}\\d\\d:ok`);

console.log(loc); // found at pos 0
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want to try regular expressions

```js
let loc;
let ftd = "17";   //ftd = first two digits
let x = "number1701:oknumber1203:ok"

const regex = /number(\d{2})\d{2}\:ok/g
  let m;

  do {
      m = regex.exec(x);
      if (m) {
      console.log(m[1]);
      } 
  } while (m);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check that out